# Get and parse data from the last message of a specific sender with python and Gmail API

Tags: python, api, gmail, gmail-api

Everyday, a sender "sender@sender.com" send me a message with a number inside.

I need to save this number everyday.

I want to write a python script with gmail API to get data from last mail from this sender, and then parse it.

I followed the Gmail API "Quickstart Guide"  : [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python)

I also check the page about User.message : [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get)

However, I don't understand how to synchronize all of this to get the data.

Could someone explain me the process ?

Answer (score 0):

If you where you able to complete the Gmail API quickstart, then you already have a GCP project, credentials and have authorized some Gmail API scopes for you app.

The above is the first step (being able to authenticate and be allowed to make requests for the API scope you need).

Since you need to pass a message's Id as a parameter for `Users.messages.get` you need to first retrieve it using listing messages for example.

So the next step is to make a request to [`Users.messages.list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) to list all messages  from a user.

> You could use the query (q) parameter to filter the messages by user like: `q="from:someuser@example.com is:unread"`.

This will return a list of messages from *someuser@example.com* that are unread.

Try things out in the API explorer sidebar from the documentation until you have defined the request as you want, and then implement it into you app.

Answer (score 0):

As aerials said.

```
    users().messages().list(userId='me',q=("<parameters>"))).execute()
```

The above code will fulfill the exact same function as typing in a search request on the gmail website. You dont actually have to worry about labels or anything if you are operating at a small scale. Just follow the same syntax as the search bar on gmail.

However, I am not sure about the usage quotas on the q parameter for list. It may be more expensive for a bigger scale operation to use the q parameter instead of using the other api methods.